# How does the kernel store the virtual memory area?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am trying to understand [`do_page_fault`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/mm/fault.c#L1034) in [`fault.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/mm/fault.c) (x86 architecture). I came across the method [`access_error`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/mm/fault.c#L982) where we compare the error code to the vm flags.

As per my understanding, we are checking an error code passed on a page fault, i.e., we are comparing the flags of a page to those of its `vm_area`. Does this imply that `vm_area` is a group of pages whose flags are the same? Specifically, does linux store or organize `vm_area` so that all pages with similar properties are together?